# How to specify multiple options (Car) in schema.org Json-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

I'm trying to describe a Car object that has multiple options regarding the engine or gearbox, that is referenced by an aggregateOffer as the itemOffered.

I want to indicate that the said Car can have either a manual or automatic gearbox, can be new or used, accept diesel or other fuels etc. The two options I see are the following :

1) Make a list with possible gearboxes and other options

```
"itemOffered" : {

    "vehicleTransmission": ["Automatic","Manual"],
    "fuelType": ["Diesel", "Essence"]

}
```

Would this be interpreted as follows : the car has either a manual OR an automatic gearbox ? 
I'm affraid the semantic behind this would suggest that the said car has both.

2) Make a list of cars with all possibilities

```
"itemOffered": [

{
        "@type": "Car1",
        "fuelType": "Essence",
        "vehicleTransmission": "Automatic" },
{
        "@type": "Car2",
        "fuelType": "Essence",
        "vehicleTransmission": "Manual" }
]
```

But this would be potentially very big, as I have multiple car offers with several different options, I would end up listing my entire database.
To clarify, the point of this Car object is to be attached to an aggregateOffer on a page where only the aggregateOffer is displayed and not every single offer available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second interpretation is correct. If you have one `Car` with multiple `fuelType` values, all of these values apply to this `Car`; they don’t represent alternatives.

Anyway, the [`AggregateOffer`](https://schema.org/AggregateOffer) doesn’t seem to be suitable for your case. This type is intended for multiple offers of the same product, not for multiple offers of different (albeit similar) products:

> When a single product is associated with multiple offers (for example, the same pair of shoes is offered by different merchants), then AggregateOffer can be used.

If you don’t want to list/repeat so many properties for each `Car`, you could make use of the [`ProductModel`](https://schema.org/ProductModel) type. You can link `ProductModel` items with the [`isVariantOf`](https://schema.org/isVariantOf) property. Each variant model will inherit the features from its base product model, unless you "overwrite" them in the variant model. Each `Car` would then use the [`model`](https://schema.org/model) property to refer to its product model.
However, if you have a specific structured data consumer in mind, they might not support this more complex structure.